# Choosing data.table keys in R

Tags: r, indexing, key, data.table

**How do I choose the right keys for `data.table` objects?**

Are the considerations similar to those for RDBMSs? My first guess was to have a look for some documentation about indexes and keys for RDBMSs. Google came up with this helpful stackoverflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/212264/how-to-choose-and-optimize-oracle-indexes) related to Oracle.

Do the considerations from that answer apply to data.tables? Perhaps with the exception of those relating to UPDATE, INSERT or DELETE type statements? I'm guessing that our `data.tables` objects won't really be used in that way.

I'm trying to get my head around this stuff by using the documentation and examples, but I haven't seen any discussion on key selection.

PS: Thanks to @crayola [pointing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5839265/r-plyr-ordering-results-from-ddply) me toward the `data.table` package in the first place!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure this is a very helpful answer, but since you mention me in the question I'll say what I think anyway. But remember that I am a bit of a `data.table` newbie myself.

I personally only use keys when there is a clear benefit for it, e.g. merging datatables, or where it seems clear that doing so will speed things up (e.g. subsetting repeatedly on a variable).
But to my knowledge, there is sometimes no real need to define keys at all; the package is already faster than `data.frame` without keys.